# C# way to set a float buffer in memory

Tags: c#

I am an usual Java developer but now I'm trying to create some OpenGL stuff in C#.

However, in Java I do it like this:

```
private FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;
private float[] vertices = new float[]{... some vertices ...};

ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
verticesBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
verticesBuffer.position(0);
```

How should I become same thing in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you need to do in C#, as presumably the types you need aren't the same. However, if you're trying to block copy floats into bytes, then [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) may be what you want. Sample code:

```
using System;

public class Test 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[12];
        float[] floats = { 1.5f, 2.5f, 0.000001f };

        Buffer.BlockCopy(floats, 0, bytes, 0, 12);

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, bytes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't alias the two arrays, which *may* be what you're after instead.

If you have specific .NET types (or .NET-translated types) in mind, it would be useful if you'd identify them.